# Accessibility error in offcanvas element in Joomla site

Tags: validation, joomla, accessibility

I have a problem with a validation error to http://www.tsiapos.gr/ (Joomla 3.9.10 - yootheme template0

https://wave.webaim.org/report#/https://tsiapos.gr/

which is related to empty link in "offcanvas"

```html
<a href="#offcanvas" class="uk-navbar-toggle uk-visible-small" data-uk-offcanvas=""></a>
```

I don't know where to find the code and how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla and Joomla extension questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like your menu button which is only visible in responsive mode.  If I increase my font size or run on mobile, then I see it.

[image]

There are two problems with the menu button.  The first is that it doesn't have a label that a screen reader can announce.  That's the error that WAVE is pointing out.  You can fix that by adding an [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) to your link.

```html
<a href="#offcanvas" aria-label="menu"></a>
```

The second problem that WAVE didn't find is that the "state" of your menu (expanded or collapsed) also needs to be conveyed.  You do that with [`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-expanded).  Set the value to "*false*" when the menu is closed and "*true*" when the menu is open.

```html
<a href="#offcanvas" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false"></a>
```

And if you want to get picky, there's a third problem that you're using a link instead of a button.  A link should be used for navigation, opening a new page, not for an "action".  I'd recommend changing your menu to a `<button>`.

If you want to use an `<a>` then you should add `role="button"` **and** make sure the <kbd>space</kbd> key can be used to select the link.  By default, links only allow the <kbd>enter</kbd> to select them but a button allows both space and enter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will have though to find where this code is located - in which joomla file- in order to change it. I have literally looked for it in every single file with no luck...

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with your file organization problem.  The code should be in the same file as the main page.  It's a responsive design so when you view on mobile or with a larger font, you're still viewing the same URL so it seems like the joomla file would be the main one for that page.